# fit axes to contain the image EXACTLY using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

i have an axes named "axes1" and an image named "im"

How to make image dimensions equal to axes dimensions?

I mean I want to fit axes to contain the image EXACTLY (don't image stretching or image compression)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the command axis image after displaying the image.

Comment: don't work

I write this code in resize button callback :

global im

prompt = {'Enter rate of increase/decrease:'};

dlg_title = 'Resize';
num_lines = 1;
sr = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines);
sr = str2double(sr);
ims=imresize(im,sr);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(ims);
axis image;

when i make sr=0.5 or sr=2 the axes dimensions don't change and the image get stretching or compression.

where is the wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question you want 1 pixel of your image to be one pixel in the axis.

You will need to do some calculating for that.

I would do it like this:

```
imagesc(magic(64)) % example image
set(gca,'Units','pixel') % set units to pixel
pos_in_px=get(gca,'Position')
set(gca,'XLim',[1,pos_in_px(3)-pos_in_px(1)]) % set xaxis to the pixel range
set(gca,'YLim',[1,pos_in_px(4)-pos_in_px(2)]) % set yaxis to the pixel range
```

of course this is a fragile solution - as you zoom or resize the window things may change.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to display a color image. Try this (copy-paste in Matlab CLI) :

```
RGB = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');
[m,n,~] = size(RGB);
figure('Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [40 40 n m]);
image(RGB);
set(gca, 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);
axis equal;
```

'ngc6543a.jpg' is a standard image provided by Matlab.